# C# / ASP Update the states of buttons in 1 row of a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

So, I got this Gridview in which what I want is, once the user clicks the 'Edit' button, that button and the delete button are replaced by another two buttons: 'Confirm' and 'Cancel', which are 'Visible = false', but only for the row they clicked it in. Here's some of my code and attempts I've made:

Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewTotal" runat="server" CssClass="list-group-item table-condensed table-hover table-responsive" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDSAdminTable" OnRowCommand="GridViewTotal_RowCommand" OnRowUpdating="GridViewTotal_RowUpdating">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonEdit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="EditData"
                                        Text="Edit" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex%>" Width="100px" Visible="true" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="DeleteData"
                                        Text="Delete" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex%>" Width="100px" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the user?');" Visible="true" />
                                     <asp:Button ID="ButtonConfirmEdit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CausesValidation="false" CommandName=""
                                        Text="Confirm" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex%>" Width="100px" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to edit the user data?');" Visible="false" />
                                     <asp:Button ID="ButtonCancelEdit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" CausesValidation="false" CommandName=""
                                        Text="Cancel" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex%>" Width="100px"  Visible="false" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Back-end:

```
 protected void GridViewTotal_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "EditData")
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewTotal.EditIndex = index;
            GridViewTotal_UpdateEditButtons(index, "edit");
            GridViewTotal.DataBind();


        }
    }
```

UpdateEditButtons():

```
protected void GridViewTotal_UpdateEditButtons(int index, string arg)
    {
        Button btnConfirm = (Button)GridViewTotal.Rows[index].FindControl("ButtonConfirmEdit");
        Button btnCancel = (Button)GridViewTotal.Rows[index].FindControl("ButtonCancelEdit");
        Button btnEdit = (Button)GridViewTotal.Rows[index].FindControl("ButtonEdit");
        Button btnDelete = (Button)GridViewTotal.Rows[index].FindControl("ButtonDelete");

        if(arg == "edit")
        {
            btnDelete.Visible = false;
            btnEdit.Visible = false;
            btnConfirm.Visible = true;
            btnCancel.Visible = true;
        }
        else if(arg == "confirm")
        {
            btnDelete.Visible = true;
            btnEdit.Visible = true;
            btnConfirm.Visible = false;
            btnCancel.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Before you ask, yes, the gridview is inside an update panel, and refreshing is working as intended.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Found the solution, using the RowDataBound event:

```
protected void GridViewTotal_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (_counter == 1)
            {
                Button btnEdit = e.Row.FindControl("ButtonEdit") as Button;
                Button btnDelete = e.Row.FindControl("ButtonDelete") as Button;
                Button btnConfirm = e.Row.FindControl("ButtonConfirmEdit") as Button;
                Button btnCancel = e.Row.FindControl("ButtonCancelEdit") as Button;

                btnCancel.Visible = true;
                btnConfirm.Visible = true;
                btnDelete.Visible = false;
                btnEdit.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using the counter variable as a state variable to see whether the function should replace or not.